# Проверка однонаправленного списка на цикличность

Tags: алгоритм

Такую задачу часто предлагают на различных собеседованиях:

Функции аргументом передается однонаправленный список, необходимо определить, является ли он цикличным. Использовать динамическую память нельзя.

Я вижу следующие варианты решения:
 1. Запомнить ссылку на второй элемент. Создать цикл в 2^32 операций, в этом цикле идти по списку, если до конца цикла ссылка не встретилась, значит это неведомый цикл, который занимает всю память(адреса то все используются)
 2. В цикле идти параллельно по списку с шагом в один элемент и с шагом в два элемента. Если в какой-либо момент времени ссылки на следующий элемент будут одинаковые, то этот список циклический.

Как то не вижу других, нормальных, решений. Они вообще есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cycle detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection)

Answer (score 0):

Второй пункт является решением, причем за O(log n), на сколько помню.

Comment: А другие способы есть?

Comment: Да, конечно. Есть много разнообразных способов. К примеру, сохраняем начальный элемент в отдельном указателе, далее двигаемся вторым указателем пока не встретим либо конец списка, либо изначально сохраненный элемент. Но я бы их даже не рассматривал. Ваш второй пункт наилучшее решение, которое я знаю.

Comment: Скорее за O(p+c), где p - длина предпериода и c - длина цикла